# Dealing with WPF errors

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've created an add-in to another software package, and this uses a WPF pane - the add-in works well.

But when I look at the Output window in Visual Studio, I see a lot of WPF errors, these are non fatal and don't seem to have any affect on my add-in, errors like:

```
System.Windows.ResourceDictionary Warning: 9 : Resource not found; ResourceKey='ActiveTabBackgroundBrush'
```

or

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 1 : Cannot create default converter to perform 'one-way' conversions between types 'System.Windows.Controls.ContextMenu' and 'System.Windows.Rect'. Consider using Converter property of Binding. BindingExpression:Path=; DataItem='ContextMenu' (Name=''); target element is 'ContextMenu' (Name=''); target property is 'PlacementRectangle' (type 'Rect')
```

or

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 5 : Value produced by BindingExpression is not valid for target property.; Value='System.Windows.Controls.ContextMenu Items.Count:0' BindingExpression:Path=; DataItem='ContextMenu' (Name=''); target element is 'ContextMenu' (Name=''); target property is 'PlacementRectangle' (type 'Rect')
```

I presume they're related to the XAML code, how can I track these down, I cant see any reference to where they are in the code and cant use break points etc to debug the code?

Thanks,

Comment: I guess you have no reference to ActiveTabBackgroundBrush in your code or markup then.   Do you have the source of the package? Without your add in you don't see these errors?

Comment: I can look through my code to try to find the errors, but theres a lot of it... Is there no way to find errors easily and quickly like you can in C# code... Cheers.

Comment: Search all includes xaml. Somewhere you have some xaml i(or code) expects to have a resource with a key ActiveTabBackgroundBrush. These errors and warnings appear as the view attempts to use them.   The way to tackle this stuff is as they appear though. If you're not iteratively developing then adopt that pra ctice. Then you know you only added a particular bit of code and that resulted in this warning has just appeared.  Of course, if everything is working ok then there's a school of thought says they're not worth fixing.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your advise, it looks like I'll have to look through the code... As you say, I did wonder if its worth fixing them as it is working fine... I'm keen to make it tidy as possible so I'll probably end up doing the work! Cheers.